# Open On Page Load

Tags: jquery, facebox

I'm using FaceBox
I'd like for it to open 1 time only on page load. I've checked there site site there aren't any instructions on this.

Usually I use a link like this to manually open the modal window.

```
<a href="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ajax:'FBhair.php'});"   onClick="self.location=this.href; return false">$15 Hair</a>
```

this script initiates facebox

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loadingImage : 'facebox/src/loading.gif',
    closeImage   : 'facebox/src/closelabel.png'
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="mylink" href="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ajax:'FBhair.php'});"   onClick="self.location=this.href; return false">$15 Hair</a>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loadingImage : 'facebox/src/loading.gif',
    closeImage   : 'facebox/src/closelabel.png'
  })
$('#mylink').click();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily fire the click event programatically

```
$(anchor_element).click();
```

or if you have one that you want, for example, add a class

```
<a href="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ajax:'FBhair.php'});"
   class="firstone"
   onClick="self.location=this.href; return false">$15 Hair</a>
```

then

```
$(".firstone").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$('a[rel*=facebox]')` part of facebox's script. That's the selector.  The default is all links with rel="facebox", but you could instead make it something like `$("#facebox")`, which will select only the object with id="facebox".  You could also do `$(".popups a")`, which will select all links inside of an element with class="popups". Finally, you can use a pseudo selector like `$(".popups a:first-child")` which will make only the first link inside of element class="popups" facebox.

Good luck.